# xelatex, polyglossia, hyperref

Tags: xetex, hyperref, polyglossia, urls, href

Using the following code with the packages hyperref and polyglossia to insert a link into a xelatex document, the link is not clickable, while in other applications as for example the email program it does work. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[xetex]{hyperref}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=old,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\setmainfont[Mapping=textext,Renderer=ICU]{Charis SIL}

\newfontfamily\germanfont[Mapping=textext,Renderer=ICU]{Charis SIL}

\begin{document}

\href{https://hikma-online.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Übersetzung-Bakker.pdf}{https://hikma-online.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Übersetzung-Bakker.pdf}

\url{https://hikma-online.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Übersetzung-Bakker.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, when I compile your code I get a pdf with clickable links. Maybe your pdf viewer does not support links at all? Which viewer do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Url must be percent encoded in a pdf. So you will have to input it like this

```
\href{https://hikma-online.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/%C3%9Cbersetzung-Bakker.pdf}
     {https://hikma-online.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Übersetzung-Bakker.pdf}
```

With the pdfmanagement, which you load with `\DocumentMetadata`, you can also use the `urlencode` option, it will then create the percent encoding internally:

```
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}


\href[urlencode]{https://hikma-online.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Übersetzung-Bakker.pdf}{https://hikma-online.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Übersetzung-Bakker.pdf}

\url[urlencode]{https://hikma-online.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Übersetzung-Bakker.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not necessarily, my viewer and browser (Evince/Firefox) correctly handle the original code to produce a link which when clicked opens the correct pdf file.

Comment: @Marijn some viewers guess correctly, but it is not reliable, believe me.

Comment: all viewers I have tried work (Evince, Okular, xpdf, Firefox pdf viewer, Chrome pdf viewer). But maybe indeed other viewers will fail.

Comment: Dear Ulrike Fischer, thank you very much for these very helpful answers, they work fine!