# Non-ASCII characters and space in link

Tags: urls

We use relative links from a PDF document. Some files have non-ASCII characters like æøå and öä or spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\url{ path with space/æøå.md }
\end{document}
```

The link works fine, but the non-ASCII characters are removed from the document. See picture below.

[image]

How can we make the non-ASCII characters show up?

**Solved**

Thanks for your comments! Switching from \url to \href fixed our issue. No encoding needed. The following code works for us:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href{ path with space/æøå.md }{ path with space/æøå.md }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @cabohah! Thanks for your answer. This may be the start of a solution. \href{} works if we convert "path with space/æøå.md" to "path%20with%20space/%E6%F8%E5.md". Do you know how to do that?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/595708/2388

Comment: Here it works with `\href{path%20with%20space/%C3%A6%C3%B8%C3%A5.md}{path with space/æøå.md}` → https://i.imgur.com/9OHaD6v.png I've removed option `hidelink` to make the link frame visible.

Comment: The spaces are probably a different issue than the non-ascii characters. Since the issue with the characters is solved using the duplicate questions I think it is better to leave this question closed and ask a new one specific for spaces (without using non-ascii characters).